# Shorten long numbers to include K/M/B/T

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've checked out Rails [`number_to_human`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human) but it's not exactly what i want.

I'd like to shorten long numbers without including the full unit name:

```
420 -> 420
5,680 -> 5,680
12,680 -> 12.6K
6,802,251 -> 6.80M
894,100,158 -> 894M
```

As you see there is no specific precision but it's more about the length of the overall number

Any one has a good helper method for this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Put in your `config/locales/en.yml`:

```
en:
  number:
    human:
      decimal_units:
        format: "%n%u"
        units:
          unit: ""
          thousand: K
          million: M
          billion: B
          trillion: T
          quadrillion: Q
```

Then you'll get:

```
number_to_human 420 # => "420"
number_to_human 5680 # => "5.68K"
number_to_human 12680 # => "12.7K"
number_to_human 6802251 # => "6.8M"
number_to_human 894100158 # => "894M"
```

Comment: Oh sorry no, I didn't mean size units, I meant Millions/Billions/Trillions :)

Comment: @Ryan And what about the "K"? What was it stood for?

Comment: @Ryan It's confusing, but the solution is pretty mush the same. Updated my answer.

Comment: You could also make it follow some standards, e.g. lowecase 'k' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_prefix#List_of_prefixes

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
number_to_human(a_number,format:'%n%u',units:{thousand:'K',million:'M',billion:'B'})
```