# How to abbreviate numbers into shortened strings

Tags: ruby, numbers, format

I have the following numbers:

```
2333
380293
1230944
```

What's the best function to turn any of those numbers into:

```
2K
380K
1.2 M
```

Comment: If you're using Rails, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585734/shorten-long-numbers-to-include-k-m-b-t) may apply.

Comment: Are you dividing by `1,000` or `1,024`?  Rounding or truncating?

Answer (score 2):

The [si](https://github.com/junegunn/si) gem will handle this for you. First install it with:

```
gem install si
```

Then just call `.si` on a number:

```
2333.si #=> 2.33k
380293.si #=> 380k
1230944.si #=> 1.23M
```

Comment: There must be a gem for everything, however trivial. Readers of the author's resume will be impressed that he created a Ruby gem. :-) (But may as well use it.)

Comment: I've created several gems, though si isn't one of them.  Not sure how my authorship of gems are pertinent here.

Comment: I think it was a general comment.

Comment: No, I saw you did not write this gem.  My point was that it would never occur to me to write a gem that replaced such a short and simple method.

Answer (score -2):

[Edit: I originally gave the [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte) representation rather than the decimal one (i.e., dividing by 1024 rather than 1000). I've concluded it is probably the digital interpretation that is desired, so I've modified my answer. Also, I've also permitted the argument to be negative, as suggested by @infused, dropped the  `"B"` in `"kB"`, `"MB"`, etc., eliminated rounding and added an optional precision argument.]

You could do this:

```
NEG_ENDINGS = { "''"=>"''", 'k'=>'m', 'M'=>'μ', 'G'=>'n', 'T'=>'p',
                'P'=>'f', 'E'=>'a', 'Z'=>'z', 'Y'=>'y' }

def convert(n, precision=0)
  raise ArgumentError, "Absolute value too big!" if n.abs >= 10**27
  raise ArgumentError, "Precision out-of-range" unless (0..3).cover?(precision)
  if n.abs < 1000
    "#{n}"
  else
    val = recurse(n.abs, precision)
    (n >= 0) ? val : "-#{val[0..-2]}#{NEG_ENDINGS[val[-1]]}"
  end        
end

def recurse(n, precision, endings = %w|k M G T P E Z Y| )
  suffix = endings.shift
  x,n = n.divmod(1000)
  if x < 1000
    unless precision.zero?
      x = "%.#{precision}f" % (x + n/1000.0)
    end  
    return "#{ x }#{ suffix }"
  end
  recurse(x, precision, endings)
end
```

```
convert 233                     #=> "233" 
convert 768                     #=> "768" 
convert -841                    #=> "-841" 
convert 999                     #=> "999" 
convert 1_000                   #=> "1k" 
convert 2_833, 1                #=> "2.8k" 
convert -2_833, 2               #=> "-2.83m" 
convert 380_293                 #=> "380k" 
convert 1_230_944, 3            #=> "1.230M" 
convert 12_309_446_125          #=> "12G" 
convert -12_309_446_125         #=> "-12n" 
convert 123_094_461_257_132_716 #=> "123P" 

convert 123_094_461_257_132_716_324_625_917_831
  #=> ArgumentError: Absolute value too big!
```

Comment: Why isn't 1_000 converted to 1k?

Comment: You might also want to add support for G between M and T

Comment: Also, seems like it should support negative numbers like -1_000 = -1k

Comment: Oh, my, another downvote! I understand why I got the first, but I then modified my answer to the point where it seemed at least decent. I would be interested in any constructive criticism.